# Galois group of polynomials related to Fibonacci and Catalan numbers

Tags: polynomials, ho.history-overview, galois-theory

Let $F_n$ be the Fibonacci and $C_n$ the Catalan numbers.
Define a polynomial by $F_n(x):=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{F_k x^{n-k}}$.

For example $F_8(x)=x^7+x^6+2x^5+3x^4+5x^3+8x^2+13x+21$.

And another polynomial  $C_n(x):=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{C_k x^{n-k}}$.

For example $C_8(x)=x^7+2x^6+5x^5+14x^4+42x^3+132x^2+429x+1430.$

> Question 1: Is $F_n(x)$ irreducible for all $n \geq 3$ and with Galois group $S_{n-1}$?
>
> Question 2: Is $C_n(x)$ irreducible for all $n \geq 3$ and with Galois group $S_{n-1}$?

Both questions have a positive answer for $n \leq 25$.

> Question 3: Is there an official english name for irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ with Galois group $S_n$? In German they are called "affektlos", see for example this article by Schur : https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/crll/1931/165/article-p52.xml .

Comment: Just a quick note: I wrote a quick GAP script that verifies that the questions have a positive answer for $n \leq 32$, which is as far as GAP can go with this at the moment.

Comment: This might be totally irrelevant but Schur showed that all truncated exponential polynomials are irreducible. See https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/schurtheorem.pdf

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda That is true for the generating function of any rational function...

Comment: It turns out that Magma can compute Galois groups far quicker than GAP can. For example, checking the Fibonacci polynomials up to $n \leq 100$ only takes a few minutes. This might be of interest to you.